# Subscript in PHP and Loops

Tags: php, css, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF and PHP to create a WordPress website currently working through basically a loop and looking to connect a subscript and a tag by an ID that needs to have a counter increment on it so that the ID can change from #footnote-top-1 to #footnote-top-2, #footnote-top-3, etc and have the link also change. , . If so how?

Preference to using PHP or CSS.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis felis ante, maximus semper malesuada vel, bibendum iaculis urna. Fusce bibendum, quam eget mollis euismod, nisl ipsum dapibus nibh, eget ultricies velit ipsum in ex. Nulla pulvinar consequat suscipit. Phasellus a bibendum nulla. Integer convallis ornare dictum. Quisque sed congue metus, ac tincidunt ex. Nulla libero nulla, aliquet vitae risus eu `<sup class="footnote" id="footnot-top-1"><a href="#footnohte-bottom-1">1</a></sup>` , rhoncus interdum ex. Vestibulum nisi nisl, sollicitudin tincidunt malesuada ut, blandit eu mi. Nam nec aliquet ante.

```
<div id="footnotes" class="footnotes">
<?php if ( have_rows( 'footnotes' ) ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_rows( 'footnotes' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
        <?php if ( have_rows( 'footnotes_group' ) ) : ?>
            <ol>
            <?php while ( have_rows( 'footnotes_group' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
                <li id="footnote-bottom-1">
                    <?php the_sub_field( 'footnotes_reference' ); ?>
                <a href="#footnote-top-1">
                    <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php the_sub_field( 'footnotes_to_number' ); ?></span>
                    <?php the_sub_field( 'footnotes_to_top' ); ?>
                </a>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ol>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php // no rows found ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php // no rows found ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to change the href value of anchor (<a>) tag each time through the loop from footnote-top-1 to footnote-top-2, etc?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do.

Comment: "If so how" - by writing some code? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div id='footnotes' class='footnotes'>
<?php if ( have_rows( 'footnotes' ) ) : ?>
<?php 
    //initialize $i with a default value of 1
    $i = 1;
    while ( have_rows( 'footnotes' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
    <?php if ( have_rows( 'footnotes_group' ) ) : ?>
        <ol>
        <?php while ( have_rows( 'footnotes_group' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
            <li id="footnote-bottom-1">
                <?php the_sub_field( 'footnotes_reference' ); ?>
            <a href="#footnote-top-<?php echo $i; //echo the current value of $i ?>">
                <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php the_sub_field( 'footnotes_to_number' ); ?></span>
                <?php the_sub_field( 'footnotes_to_top' ); ?>
            </a>
            </li>
        <?php 
    //increment $i by one each time through the loop
    $i++; endwhile; //have_rows( 'footnotes_group' ) ?>
        </ol>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php // no rows found ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php 
    endwhile; //while ( have_rows( 'footnotes' ) ) ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php // no rows found ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: The solution required a default value of 1 using $i a variable to set a default value of 1. By opening the loop outside of the OL and closing it Inside of the OL it allowed the loop to create a counter for each link tag (a) that started at one. The variable is also attached to the footnote-top ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable named $i, that initialize before the 'footnotes' loop.  Echo the variable each time you want that value, then increment the variable at the end of each iteration through the loop.

```
<div id='footnotes' class='footnotes'>
<?php if ( have_rows( 'footnotes' ) ) : ?>
<?php 
    //initialize $i with a default value of 1
    $i = 1;
    while ( have_rows( 'footnotes' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
    <?php if ( have_rows( 'footnotes_group' ) ) : ?>
        <ol>
        <?php while ( have_rows( 'footnotes_group' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
            <li id="footnote-bottom-1">
                <?php the_sub_field( 'footnotes_reference' ); ?>
            <a href="#footnote-top-<?php echo $i; //echo the current value of $i ?>">
                <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php the_sub_field( 'footnotes_to_number' ); ?></span>
                <?php the_sub_field( 'footnotes_to_top' ); ?>
            </a>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; //have_rows( 'footnotes_group' ) ?>
        </ol>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php // no rows found ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php 
    //increment $i by one each time through the loop
    $i++;
    endwhile; //while ( have_rows( 'footnotes' ) ) ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php // no rows found ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I was thinking of doing - just wasn't sure if it could be accomplished. The only thing is i is not changing at the moment. So I have to figure out why.

Comment: @BecWestcott  Glad you got it working!  Can you please mark this answer as accepted?

Comment: Had to be adjusted a bit though.

Comment: @BecWestcott   Then post your own answer please, with the solution.  This is a community and we all learn from each other.  Please share the solution that worked for you.  If my answer was helpful, please upvote it.

Comment: I did post the answer with the final solution and checked mark it, please keep in mind I am still learning Stack Overflow as well.

Comment: @BecWestcott  Your code looks exactly like mine with one edit to where the increment was.  In my experience, that would be considered an accepted answer.